# i want to store text under p tag in javascript variable then show in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want store text in p tag in javascript varible and then text show in input field.

```
<p id="txt" onclick="check();">yes i am stroe in js variable</p>
<input id="show" type="text" name="" disabled="">

    <script type="text/javascript">
function check() {
    var input = document.getElementById("txt").text;

    document.getElementById("show")=input.value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You just have `.value `in the wrong place: `document.getElementById("show").value=input;` Also, `p` elements don't have a `text`; they have `innerHTML` or `innerText`/`textContent`. Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future

Comment: You've tagged the question [tag:jquery] but haven't used any jQuery in it. Are you sure you need/want to use jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7uf6zc17/)

To get the content inside a `<p>`, you have to use `innerHTML` instead of `value`.

Read more about innerHTML in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Thus, your `script` should be rewritten as

```
function check() {
    var input = document.getElementById("txt");
    document.getElementById("show").value=input.innerHTML;
}
```

```js
function check() {
    var input = document.getElementById("txt");
    document.getElementById("show").value=input.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<p id="txt" onclick="check();">yes i am stroe in js variable</p>
<input id="show" type="text" name="" disabled="">
```

### OR

If you want to use a **jQuery solution**,

change your `script` as follows

```
function check() {
    var input = $("#txt");
    $("#show").val(input.text());
}
```

See the snippet below..

```js
function check() {
    var input = $("#txt");
    $("#show").val(input.text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="txt" onclick="check();">yes i am stroe in js variable</p>
<input id="show" type="text" name="" disabled="">
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('show').value = input ;

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<p id="PTag">Hello :D</p>
<a id="Btn">click me</a>
```

use text in script

```
<script>
  $('#Btn').click(function () {
     var hello= $("#PTag").html($("#text").val())[0].innerHTML; 
     alert(hello)
  })
</script>
```

result
======>>>>
**Hello :D**